# Configuring two 1-1 or 0 and 1-many relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

With EF6 I have two models that have two relationships with each other. We have some notes and each note might have many revisions. Each note also might have none or one revision as its `CurrentRevision`.

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentRevision")]
    public long? CurrentRevisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual NoteRevision CurrentRevision { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NoteRevision> Revisions { get; set; }
}

public class NoteRevision
{

    [Key]
    public long NoteRevisionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Note")]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

`Add-Migration` and `DbContext.SaveChanges` try to create and access a new column named `Note_NoteId` with error

> Invalid Column Name: Note_NoteId

which doesn't make sense to me because such column is unnecessary. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not need to use `ForeignKey` attribute, `NoteId` already follows the convention for the binding between your navigation property and `Note` class. I do not think this is going to solve your problem, though. just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Just in case, try with building your model using fluent api.